# Is it possible on Linux to run a DRM app that takes over the screen while the X server is active?

Tags: c, linux, opengl, drm, xorg

I have a simple app that launches and then draws a color full-screen using EGL/OpenGL ES. I am using DRM and GBM. It works great if I switch to a framebuffer console and launch from there. However, if I try to run it while the X server is active, the DRM permissions prevent me from doing so. I assume this is because the X server already has "master" control over DRM. Is there any way to override this and have a DRM app take over the screen, then return control to the X server once it completes? This would be preferable to having to switch to a console using ctrl+alt+FX first. I am running Ubuntu 22.

Mesa includes a "drmSetMaster" function in xf86drm.h:
https://github.com/freedesktop/mesa-drm/blob/master/xf86drm.h

However, I just get the same "permission denied" error. When I run as root, I get a "Device or resource busy" error.

Comment: You want a DRM-lease: https://keithp.com/blogs/DRM-lease/

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you. I followed the example and borrowed code from kmscube.c (opening the fd OK, passing my encoder_id, connector_id and crtc_id as objects to drmModeCreateLease), but drmModeGetLease and drmModeListLessees both return NULL, and drmModeCreateLease returns a negative fd. What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: The `drm…` functions are meant to be used by the display server. Client applications have to use a display protocol specific function. On the Wayland side it's the typical hodgepodge of ad-hoc implementations that may or may not find their way into each existing compositor. On the Xorg side DRM leasing was added to XRandR-1.6 https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/xorg/proto/xorgproto/-/blob/master/randrproto.txt#L1727

Comment: @datenwolf If I use a static version of libXrandr 1.6, does that mean my entire X installation must be updated to match? Can I be assured a statically-linked version of my binary will work on recent distros running X?

Comment: Since X11 has a well defined wire protocol, that also pins down how file descriptors are passed, there's no tie to a particular build of the client libraries (unless you're making use of Vulkan or direct context GLX – then you must use the `libX*.so` `libxcb*.so` so that the OpenGL / Vulkan implementation uses the same codepath as your program). – However XRandR-1.6 also must be supported by the X server, so you *must* check the available version before hand.

Comment: I’m restarting a DRM project myself. Ideally, the app will figure out if Wayland owns the display and do the right thing (I’m thinking the post-X era will be here by the time I get anything working). I was planning to have a wayland client mode, but maybe I can use a DRM-lease instead. Anybody have experience with how well a DRM lease app plays with Wayland, in terms of fast switching between apps and/or multi monitor setups, with debugger on one screen, fullscreen app on another?

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is to use the KMS API to create a new “DRM plane” (a.k.a. “overlay”) and display your content there. The DRM API does not have a mechanism to “take over the screen”, what it gives you is a way to create new planes and display content on those planes. The display controller will then take care of compositing those planes together and displaying the result. Each display controller has its own way of handling planes, but typically the most complex display controllers will give you the greatest control over how the planes are composed. The best way to get started on this is to look at the source code for the DRM drivers in the kernel. For example, the Intel DRM driver contains a full-featured KMS API implementation. This is a large and complex driver, but it should give you a good idea of what’s possible with the KMS API.

Comment: Thanks. I'll look into this. I am using a machine with Intel graphics, so this is good news. I still need to check for vblank using drmModePageFlip. Will this still work as expected after creating a new plane?

Comment: This became a requirement for all windows HW a while back (5 years?) the display engines are pretty sophisticated, able to composite multiple layers of different resolutions on scan out (even upscaling lo-res YUV to desktop Res RGB, which is more memory efficient than using the 3D engine if the update rate is near the display refresh rate.).